# OnServerClick on anchor tag is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

I have 3 tabs, On which I want to show the respective data. I have given a attribute as `onserverclick` to the anchor tag inside `<li>`. but the problem is that it is not firing.

Also When I tried putting a breakpoint it was not working. Here is my piece of html code:-

```
<ul class='tabs1'>
            <li><a href='#tab1' id="allNews" runat="server" onserverclick="allNews_ServerClick">All News</a></li>

            <li><a href='#tab2' id="forNgo" runat="server" onserverclick="forNgo_ServerClick">For NGO</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab3' id="fromNgo" runat="server" onserverclick="fromNgo_ServerClick">From NGO</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Please suggest what might be the issue which is preventing to work.

**UPDATE**

Server code:-

```
protected void fromNgo_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {   
            string query = "SSELECT dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.active, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, dbo.tbl_User.usertype FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_User ON dbo.tbl_post.UserId = dbo.tbl_User.Id INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id AND dbo.tbl_User.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id WHERE (dbo.tbl_User.usertype=2)";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it like that. Try to use the Hyperlink control which exactly does what you want. You could also use a LinkButton for this purpose.

Comment: @SorrelVesper: Which one will be better, as I also want to write some `server side code` related to it ??

Comment: @SorrelVesper, that should be entirely possible with HTMLAnchor control. But agreed that Hyperlink should be a preferred way

Comment: @Geeker, can you show your fromNgo_ServerClick method declaration?

Comment: What I would suggest is to load all the tabs on the first visit and not on the tab clicks since you are not getting any parameters from other tabs. It will make your life easier and of those to come after you.

Comment: @SorrelVesper: Agreed, could you be more specific by writing it in code. So that I can check it with my requirement

Comment: @Andrei: Any help or sugesstion related to this..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the Click event for Anchor tag in page load as below

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
HtmlAnchor HA = new HtmlAnchor();
HA.ServerClick += new EventHandler(linkclickeve1);
HtmlAnchor HA2 = new HtmlAnchor();
HA2.ServerClick += new EventHandler(linkclickeve2);
}

protected void linkclickeve1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void linkclickeve2(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}
```

[Example Here](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/02/creating-onserverclick-event-to-anchor.html)

Comment: create the click events for all the three anchor tags as Shown for one

Comment: just go through the Example link given below the code . it will take you to server side

Comment: Yes, but still not working..!! Getting the same data for every `tabs`

Comment: nothing different, same thing is happening still..!! See the code  `HtmlAnchor HA = new HtmlAnchor();
            HA.ServerClick += new EventHandler(allNews_ServerClick);

            HtmlAnchor HA2 = new HtmlAnchor();
            HA2.ServerClick += new EventHandler(forNgo_ServerClick);

            HtmlAnchor HA3 = new HtmlAnchor();
            HA3.ServerClick += new EventHandler(fromNgo_ServerClick);`

Comment: Venki, I somehow managed to get the solution from your code,Thanks a lot..! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Tab1Function()
    {   
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {   
            string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.active, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, dbo.tbl_User.usertype FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_User ON dbo.tbl_post.UserId = dbo.tbl_User.Id INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id AND dbo.tbl_User.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id WHERE (dbo.tbl_User.usertype=2)";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And then, use this in your PageLoad

```
    If (!IsPostBack)
     {
       Tab1Function();
     }
```

Something like that.

EDIT: I think your tabs are not working. So lets direct you to the TabContainer then.

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="Tab_Container" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" CssClass="CustomTabStyle" EnableTheming="False" ScrollBars="Both" Style="vertical-align: top" Width="900px">
 <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel_1" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ScrollBars="Both">
 <HeaderTemplate> All News </HeaderTemplate>
   <ContentTemplate>
//Your Table/Datagrid containing your data here.. Whatever you are binding your data to.
 <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>

 </ContentTemplate>
                                    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel_2" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel3">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            For NGO
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ContentTemplate>
 <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
</ContentTemplate></ajaxToolkit:TabPanel></ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So, do i need `onServerClick` attribute now ?? or what should I add in the anchor tag to work. you did not mentioned the aspx part here. Please mention that

Comment: I haven't tested your code, so if there's any error, make sure you fix it. I am just suggesting a BindFunciton that is used in the Page_Load so that it binds the data on the user's first visit and make sure not to rebind it on every postback. No you don't need onServerClick anymore.

Comment: So how will it differentiate that which tab is clicked as I have `three tabs` now ??

Comment: Just using the href will do the trick. I partially understand what you are trying to do here. Do you want to send the user to another page where you are populating the data? If yes, then use this Tab1Function in that page's pageload and just use href for the redirection.

Comment: Does your tabs work or not as it is? Can you switch between tabs? Or are you just redirecting user to another page?

Comment: No, I dont want to send to another page. What I want is. There are three different types of data at each tab based on `UserId`. I want just whenever a user wants to see the data of `From NGO` he will click that and he will get the data then and there only

Comment: Sorry, net was disabled. Let me try and check. I have 3 simple tabs. Not with the ajax what you gaved